# Transform varchar with non numeric char to date

Tags: sql, string-to-datetime

I have date like `'Mon Sep 14 09:03:10 +0000 2015'`, that I did not succeed in transforming them into date format

Already tried to_date/to_timestamp and different format spec

For example:

```
select TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ('Mon Sep 14 09:03:10 +0000 2015') from dual;
```

I expect to retrieve something like `'DD/MM/YYYY'`.

Comment: Could you tag which RDBMS you use? (Oracle, MS SQL Server, MySQL ...)

Comment: Looks like Oracle? If it is, add the <oracle> tag to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Oracle:

```
select 
TO_CHAR(CAST(SUBSTR(TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ('Mon Sep 14 09:03:10 +0000 2015', 'DY Mon dd HH24:MI:SS TZHTZM YYYY'),1,9) AS DATE),'DD/MM/YYYY')
from dual;
```

Output:

```
14/09/2015
```

Comment: Thank you very much Gen Wan.... Could you explain why is it necessary to use cast? Perfect query!!!! thx a lot!!!

Comment: @TristanSalord Because I used TO_CHAR function to convert it to a specific format and it requires that the expression is datetime or similar data type. ( I cast it as date). If you think my answer works for you, please click the check button  below 'vote up/down' to accept this answer.

Answer (score 0):

This should work in Oracle:

```
select TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ('Mon Sep 14 09:03:10 +0000 2015', 'DY MON dd HH24:MI:SS TZHTZM YYYY')
from dual;
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok so Gen Wan solution works pretty fine and at the end i was near the solution but i had to change my sqldevelopper language to english in order to work. If you use Sql developper in other language it won't recognize the timestamp format answearing "this is not a valid day of the week".

So Solution of Gen Wan : select 
TO_CHAR(CAST(SUBSTR(TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ('Mon Sep 14 09:03:10 +0000 2015', 'DY Mon dd HH24:MI:SS TZHTZM YYYY'),1,9) AS DATE),'DD/MM/YYYY')
from dual;

Thanks to him a lot!

Comment: [What should I do when someone answer's my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)